# Change bootstrap card outline with javascript

Tags: bootstrap-5

Right now I want to make a minecraft server status on my website and I have everything working but I want to do something that if server is online card outline is green and when server is offline same card turns red.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS variable `--bs-card-border-color` for the Card component is what you're looking for I believe. Make sure to use your browser's developer tools to view a card's CSS variables when looking for a particular component oriented styling.

```css
.card.green {
  --bs-card-border-color: green !important;
}

.card.red {
  --bs-card-border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example">
    <!-- Card - Green -->
    <div class="card green" style="width: 18rem;">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="180" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Card - Red -->
    <div class="card red" style="width: 18rem;">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="180" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```